# generate a model with a string field as primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-activerecord, primary-key

I want to create a `User` model inside my Ruby on Rails application.

I use following command:

```
rails generate model User email:string name:string role:string
```

It is possible to define the `email` as primary key with this command? Or I must modify the database migration file that I create with this command? And how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't. By default the primary key is an auto-increment integer.

However, you can open the migration that was generated from the command, and change it (before running the `rake db:migrate` command). The migration will likely have a `create_table` command:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

If you read the [`create_table`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table) documentation, you will notice you can pass two options. Specifically, you need to set `:id` to `false` to not generate an `id` field, and you will need to specify the name of the primary key field.

```
    create_table :users, id: false, primary_key: :email do |t|
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the reply. I'll change the migration file then.

Answer (score 8):

To add to `@Simone Carletti`'s answer, you *may* need to use `execute` to set the `primary key` (if it's obscure). This would be especially true if you're modifying an existing table, which you're obviously not doing:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table :users, id: false do |t|
         t.string :email, null: false
         t.timestamps
      end
      execute "ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (email);"
   end
end
```

We use `uuid`'s in some of our apps, and that's what we had to do (`primary_key: :uuid` didn't work)...

[image]

---

Answer (score 2):

In Migration 6.0 or Rails 6

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
   def change
       create_table :users, id: false do |t|
           t.string :email, null: false, primary_key: true
           t.timestamps
       end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of ActiveRecord you can use `--primary-key-type` to specify the primary key type in the generate command:

```sh
rails generate model User email:string --primary-key-type=string
```

produces the migration:

```rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users, id: :string do |t|
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

However, as far as I can tell there's still no way to change the name of the primary key column, except by hand.